# logits and labels must have the same shape error in skincancer image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

i am using latest tensorflow package and isic skin cancer image dataset. am completely new to this machine learning and neural nets and was trying to classify images using tensorflow neural networks and keras.

i used the code off from kaggle and changed it a bit up to suit my need for the model however the code is not running and giving me an error that i am not understanding and able to do anything as the vanialla code ran just fine.

How to resolve this error?

this is the function that i have written to make the nerural network. The code is based of from a kaggle project and i have tried to make functions which can be used to easily supply desired parameters and hyper parameters to easily train the models.

```
#function to select the optimizers
def select_optimizer(optimizer , lr):
    optimizers = {
      "adam": tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
      "sgd": tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr),
      "lion": tf.keras.optimizers.Lion(learning_rate = lr),
      "adafactor": tf.keras.optimizers.Adafactor(learning_rate = lr)}
    return optimizers[optimizer]
   
# final function that compiles the prototype model and gets the model and history    
def proto_model(n , neuron_density , num_classes , acti_functions , final_acti , lr , loss_func , optimize , epochs):
    
    model = Sequential([layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255 , input_shape = (img_height , img_width , 3))])
    #initial properties of the layer of the neurons in the first element of the arrays 
    model.add(Conv2D(neuron_density[0] , 3 , padding = "same" , activation = acti_functions[0]))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    #for loop for the internal desne layer creations
    for i in range(1 , n):
        model.add(Conv2D(neuron_density[i] , 3 , padding = "same" , activation = acti_functions[i]))
        model.add(MaxPool2D())
    
    
    #final output dense layer of the neurons taken from the final layer of the arrays 
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(neuron_density[n-1] , activation = acti_functions[n-1]))
    model.add(Dense(units = num_classes , activation = final_acti))
    
    optimizer_algo = select_optimizer(optimize , lr)
    model.compile(optimizer = optimizer_algo, loss = loss_func,
    metrics = ['accuracy'])
     
    history = model.fit(train_ds , validation_data = val_ds , epochs = epochs)
    
    return model , history
```

The parameters that i have supplied :-

```
densities = [32 , 64 , 128 , 256 , 512 , 1024] 
acties = ["relu" , "relu" , "relu" , "relu" , "relu" , "relu"] 
fin_acti = "softmax"
n = 6
classes = 9
learning_rate = 0.001
loss_func = "BinaryCrossentropy"
optimizer = "adam"
epochs = 10
model , history = proto_model(n , densities , classes , acties , fin_acti , learning_rate , loss_func , optimizer , epochs)
```

The above were the exact parameters that were even in vanilla original code however this time i have made it into arrays and supplied to the function that i have created from the vanilla code.

Error that i have encountered :
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 9) vs (None, 1)).

also shows :-

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 10
      8 optimizer = "adam"
      9 epochs = 10
---> 10 model , history = proto_model(n , densities , classes , acties , fin_acti , learning_rate , loss_func , optimizer , epochs)

Cell In[24], line 33, in proto_model(n, neuron_density, num_classes, acti_functions, final_acti, lr, loss_func, optimize, epochs)
     29 optimizer_algo = select_optimizer(optimize , lr)
     30 model.compile(optimizer = optimizer_algo, loss = loss_func,
     31 metrics = ['accuracy'])
---> 33 history = model.fit(train_ds , validation_data = val_ds , epochs = epochs)
     35 return model , history

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File C:\Users\SUBHOJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileoc8gwbam.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:
```

Comment: It is possible that you are passing the labels in the wrong format? with the error message it is difficult to know what exactly is going on but from my experience it seems to be an issue with the encoding of the labels. I see that you have 9 classes (I guess from 0 to 8), I think you are passing the labels as a value instead of in one hot encoding format. That is, instead of passing label 6 (for example), you should pass the one hot version of that [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. This way, the size of the labels [1, 9] matches the size of the logits (last layer of your network) [1, 9]

Comment: Probably a mismatch as stated above, you can check the output shape at each layer of your model by printing the keras model.summary()

Comment: @Cuartero can you please tell me like what change i should make in the code in order to like pass the labels in that format ? is there like some numpy method to use ? ......... would be pretty helpful

Comment: @PaoloJ42 the model is not compiling due to that error unfortunately and am not being able to run model.summary() cause of that 

Comment: Where are u creating the `train_ds` variable?

Comment: @Cuartero   `# The Training dataset for using the training split of the images
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir_train,
    validation_split = 0.2 , 
    subset = "training" ,
    seed = 123 , 
    image_size = (img_height , img_width) ,
    batch_size = batch_size 
)` This is the train_ds code and similarly the validation and test ones are cerated too

Comment: however , i am putting the units parameter in the model.add(Dense(units = )) and that i know gives the dimension of the output ......... it worked before when i didnt turn the vanilla code into a function but jst passed 9 directly but it doesnt work now 

Comment: You can add the input `label_mode` to `image_dataset_from_directory` and try as follows. `train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(     data_dir_train,     validation_split = 0.2 ,      subset = "training" ,     seed = 123 ,      image_size = (img_height , img_width) ,     batch_size = batch_size,  label_mode = "categorical")`

Comment: just did that @Cuartero thanx a lott  fixed it ╰(*°▽°*)╯ .......... if possible can u explain like how did that end up working

Answer (score 2):

As I said in comments, the error was because the model output (last layer) expected the labels in one hot encoding format. The layer had been defined as a dense layer of size `(None, num_classes)` (where None refers to the batch size) i.e. the labels should be in one hot encoding format. This format consists of vectors of size `num_classes` (one entry for each class). Thus, for the class, for example, 6, instead of having a number representing it, we have a vector of size 9 (number of classes) where position 5 (label 6) contains a 1 while the others contain 0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. In reality, what this format represents is a vector where each index corresponds to the probability of each of the classes.

Tensorflow allows encoding labels in this format within the `image_dataset_from_directory` function using the input variable `label_mode = "categorical"`.

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
       ...
       label_mode = "categorical"
)
```